# Почему PHPMailer вставляет пустой тег <img>?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Например я вставляю в текст письма картинку:

```
 <img src="' . $img_name . '" alt="QR Code" />
```

но в письме приходит

```
<img alt="QR Code">
```

Comment: значение переменной $img_name пробовали вывести где нибудь?

Comment: да. путь правильный. после того как добавил в начало "http://" путь к файлу появился но вместо src теперь _src

Comment: А где вы смотрите итоговый код письма?

Answer (score 0):

выполните подряд эти действия, на определенном этапе, я уверен, все разрешится

1) попробуйте вместо переменной вставить текст как вы это сделали с атрибутом alt, картинка или путь к ней в исходнике письма, должна вывестись в любом случае

2) попробуйте перед этим участком кода вручную явно определить переменную $img_name, также при помощи var_dump проверьте ее содержимое, до и после на соответствие